# How can I add auto_increment field?

Tags: forms

My requirement I want to create one custom module with some form field like id(auto_increment),first name,last name,date of birth.

I want to store all the information in Drupal database through but id will be auto_increment.

Comment: You are describing what you want to achieve, but you don't ask any explicit question. It's not clear if you don't know how to create a form with the necessary fields, or if you don't know how to create a database when a module you create is installed. In both these cases, the question is too broad: We should report here the full documentation you find on drupal.org, since you didn't point out what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [hook_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7)

The field you enter for the primary key will automatically become an auto_increment field. Example from node module. As [Vishal Kumar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/53035/vishal-kumar) mentioned you need to register the field as `serial` as well. Both aspects combined make the field suitable for use as an identifier field.

```
function hook_schema() {
  $schema['node'] = array(
    // Example (partial) specification for table "node".
    'description' => 'The base table for nodes.',
    'fields' => array(
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),

      // ... (Any other fields)

    ),
    'indexes' => array(
    ),
    'unique keys' => array(
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by @Neograph734 works.

Making field `serial` makes it `INT auto_increment`.

> Use 'serial' for auto incrementing fields. This will expand to 'INT auto_increment' on MySQL.

Check the link: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7

Comment: You are very right... Totally missed that one.